# Website slow because of a lot of images

Tags: html, image, performance

My website is really slow because I have a lot of images.

Does somebody know a way to make it fast so I can keep all the images?

Comment: Lower resolution images, loading images after the webpage (lazy), different options out there. What have you tried? Show us some code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use [tiny png](http://tinypng.com/) to compress you images and replace them with existing images as lower resolution images will helps the page to browse fast.
2. Place all your javascripts to bottom of you page and use deferred parsing of some javascripts that are not in use on initial load this will help you page to load first and unnecessary scripts will load later.
3. Try to minify all you js and css which will remove you file size as well as page size.

> Above are some basic points we need to take care of while developing a website.

Read this tutorial too to learn more things about it http://learntocodewith.me/posts/make-your-website-fast/

Comment: How do I make it so the javascript only loads when it is needed?

Comment: read this https://gtmetrix.com/defer-parsing-of-javascript.html